# Pass file contents to linux command arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have the randomly generated password stored in `/tmp/mysqlpwd.txt`

I would like to set the contents of that file as the password in an automated installation.
I tried:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $(cat /tmp/mysql_passwd.txt)"
```

But the password just becomes `$(cat /tmp/mysql_passwd.txt)`

I also tried using backticks around the `$(cat /tmp/mysql_passwd.txt)` but the password adds the backticks.

How do I pass the contents of the file to the command?

Comment: I wonder if, perhaps, in testing this you used a different kind of quotes than the (correct) double quotes you used in the question here. (This is part of why including a tested reproducer for a problem is so important!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is already correct as-written (though it's putting content on stdin rather than arguments, that's what `debconf-set-selections` expects).

You can test this trivially:

```
echo "hello world" >file
cat <<<"content follows: $(cat file)"
```

...the output of the above being:

```
content follows: hello world
```

---

Incidentally, when your shell is known to be bash you might consider `$(<file)` as a more efficient replacement to `$(cat file)`.

Comment: Why is  `$(<file)` a more efficient replacement to `$(cat file)`? @charles-duffy

Comment: Then how can I pass the content of the file to `debconf-set-selections`?

Comment: @sjsam, `$(cat file)` is inefficient because it spawns a subprocess, and then executes the external `/bin/cat` command in that subprocess, reading its output from a pipe -- whereas `$(<file)` just has the shell itself read the file directly.

Comment: @pleasega, ...your code already *does* pass the content of the file on the stdin of `debconf-set-selections`, if it's exactly as given in your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But why does it result in the code instead of the contents?

Comment: @pleasega, I don't accept your assertion that it does as true. Probably, you used the wrong quotes.

Comment: @pleasega, ...replace `debconf-set-selections` with `cat` in your command. What does it include in its output? Does it show that the shell did or did not perform the replacement as requested?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used the code exactly in my question, using the double quotation, but strangely it didn't take in the contents. Which is what made me ask this question. Should I try a single quotation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110065/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-pleasega).